# Angular form only works on app.component.html

Tags: forms, angular, angular-forms

I want to use a form in an component that uploads images, but I can only use form in my `app.component.html`.

In my `app.module.ts` I have

```
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

imports: [
    ReactiveFormsModule,
```

In my `app.component.ts` I have:

```
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

rForm: FormGroup;
post:any;                     // A property for our submitted form
description:string = '';
name:string = '';

constructor (
    private fb: FormBuilder) {
    console.log('AppComponent constructor');
    this.rForm = fb.group({
        'name' : [null, Validators.required],
        'description' : [null, Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.minLength(30), Validators.maxLength(500)])],
        'validate' : ''
    });

}
```

And finally in my `app.component.html` I have this:

```
<form [formGroup]="rForm" (ngSubmit)="addPost(rForm.value)">
   <div class="form-container">
     <div class="row columns">
       <h1>My Reactive Form</h1>
       <label>Name
         <input type="text" formControlName="name">
       </label>

       <label>Description
         <textarea  formControlName="description"></textarea>
       </label>

       <label for="validate">Minimum of 3 Characters</label>
       <input type="checkbox" name="validate" formControlName="validate" value="1"> On

       <input type="submit" class="button expanded" value="Submit Form" [disabled]="!rForm.valid">
     </div>
   </div>
```

When I compile this I get to see the form without problem.

But when I try to create a form in a different component, such as upload `/upload/upload.component.html` I get a error:

Uncaught Error: Template parse errors: Can't bind to 'formGroup' since it isn't a known property of 'form'.

So it looks like the import statements from app.module.ts don't get recognized by `/upload/upload.component.ts`

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Which module your `/upload/upload.component.ts` belongs? make sure you import `FormsModule` in it as well

Comment: I didn't create the app and there's little documentation. But as far as I can see the upload doesn't have it's own module and I thought it would then use the app.module

Comment: You need to declare that component inside of a module that imports the ReactiveForms module

Comment: I just figured out that the component I wanted to use, was already imported by another components module. But that module didn't import `ReactiveFormsModule`, so I added that line (and the import) and it fixed the problem. I learned a lot about modules and components.